# PyQt Qstring not accepted when script run from WIndows command line, why?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, pyqt4, qstring

Using PyQt 4, Python 2.7, Windows 7 on a x64 machine.

I have been developing a bit of code using a Python console with PyQt4 and passing strings from QLineEdit() widgets to OS commands with no issues using `os.system(cmd)`

But when I tried running from the command line in Windows I get the following error,

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, QString found

I got around this by converting the offending string via `str(cmd)` but it has left me curious about, why this should happen only when the code is called from the command line and not when called within a Python console?

Comment: Which python console were you using? ipython? normal python?

Comment: A normal Python console.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this is happening exactly (given that you're just using the standard Python console), but it is possible to configure PyQt methods to return python strings rather than `QStrings`. I suspect that your Python console is doing this, but your script is not. Again, I really can't see why the normal python console would do this automatically, unless our definition of a normal python console is somehow different (by normal console I mean running just `python.exe` from a terminal). However, it is the only explanation I have short of you actually running different code in the console and not realising.

So, the [PyQt documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) covers how to disable `QStrings` using the `sip` module. You just do this **before** importing PyQt4.

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
```

If you do this in your Python script, then you should get identical behaviour between the console and the command line.

You can also do a similar thing to disable `QVariant` and other annoying Qt types that are often pointless in Python.

Answer (score -1):

I think that this problem happens because the command line parameters are actually byte arrays and not strings, strings are encoded in Unicode, but byte arrays are not. Calling `str(cmd)` return the content of `cmd` as a string.